# Load data from AngularJS controller in ASP.NET MVC without loading entire page

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

Here is my Action:

```
    [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult GetData()
    {
            //get data from DB and populate model with data
            return View("Data", model);
    }
```

The view is:

```
    @model UI.Models.DataModel

    @{
var grid = new WebGrid(Model.listTest, 
    null, 
    defaultSort: "Id", 
    rowsPerPage: 25, 
    canPage: true, 
    canSort: true
    );
    }

    @if (Model.listTest != null)
    {

     @grid.GetHtml()

    }
```

In this particular case, how can one populate the gridview without loading entire page after the action is called using angularjs (not Ajax)?

I have not written a single line of code for making it asynchronous because I don't know anything about angularjs. This will be my first step towards learning it.

Update:

- I know how this can be done in Ajax, I wanted to learn AngularJS. Is it better to do such things in Ajax only? Or AngularJS is better than Ajax?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to have asynchronous API calls back to a controller, I highly recommend looking at the ASP.NET website, which contains information on this subject specifically.

The simplest answer before I link to an article is that you will want to split up your controller actions to use one for the View specifically, and another action which returns the data asynchronously.

Here is a link to an article which answers your question:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4

Comment: Started reading the article however does it relates to AngularJS?

Comment: Using MVC or Web API you can return JSON which is consumed by AngularJS. Generally you will want to load the data in to an array in your Angular ViewModel and populate it from an AJAX call to the controller's action.

Comment: I'm sorry, my question is not about *backend* and AngularJS takes care of front end. This is not the answer I was looking for. However, thanks a lot man! **The article tells how to squeeze 5000 requests to 50 requests!**

Comment: If you're looking to create Async requests, you have to work on both sides, both the back-end and the front-end. The article discusses how to create an asynchronous method which you will need to achieve what you wanted. Angular has AJAX functionality built in through the $http factory, which is what you would use to call the async method.